# missed calls notification when app is not active

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I wrote a contact-list-app with a BroadcastReceiver (for phone states) that notifies the user about each missed call with the help of the WindowManager (similar to the reminders in apps like "any.do"). the problem is that this only works as long as my app is running, as soon as i close it, this notification seems to be disabled. but the user should get a clear message about each missed call (including spectial feature about handling this missed call) also when the app is not active.

this is my receiver

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static String lastState = TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE;

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
```

and this is the part of the AndroidManifest for it

```
<receiver android:name="addressbook.CallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

my next step was to write a service to do this job, and to check out if this does what i want. the idea was not to use a BroadcastReceiver but to register a contentObserver in a service, that checks if new missed calls exist in the call-logs. i tried to follow all advices i could find in this forum about services, but i could not start that service.

this is the part in the AndroidManifest

```
 <service 
        android:name="addressbook.ContentObserverService"
        android:enabled="true"/>
```

and this is the place where i try to start that service in AddressBook.java

```
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContentObserverService.class));

public class ContentObserverService extends Service {

private Observer observer;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    D.d("observer created");
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    observer = new Observer(handler);
    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Calls.CONTENT_URI, true, observer);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    D.d("onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(observer);
}
```

but neither the onCreate nor the onStartCommand method gets called, and i dont get any errors or warnings.

so i have two questions:

1. is a service the right solution for my problem, or is there a better solution existing
2. if the service is the right solution, why is it not starting?

EDIT: the strang thing is that the solutin with the broadcastreceiver always worked on the emulator (even when my app closes). the problem only occurs when i get a call to my real mobile phone.

Answer (score 1):

Do as follows,

1) Register a PhoneStateChange receiver. [Tutorial for BroadCast receiver](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

2) check whether it is missed call.

3) if it was a missed call start a intentService to show notification. [Tutorial for intentService](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#service_intentservices)

**Edit:-** Registering Receiver in Manifest so it can work even if app is not opened.

1) create a independent class(No inner class) extends it with Broadcast Receiver. [see in detail here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html#tutorial_receiver)

2) you need to add Receiver in AndroidManifest file. like below

```
    <receiver android:name="MyPhoneReceiver" > // this is name of your receiver class
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

3) take appropriate permission , one is

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

and it will work even your app is closed

Comment: but the problem is that the PhoneStateChange receiver does not work when my app is closed, so step three will never happen if the app is not active. if step 1 would work for a closed app i would not have any problems.

so another question would be. what shall i in order to make my receiver work even when the app is closed

Comment: thanks, but thats what i did. and it only works when the app is not closed

Comment: Your reciever might be working but not service, as you are not starting it from Receiver itself

Comment: i hv same prob can you give proper example??? i want to send message to person if got miscall instead of notification